# DirectShow filters -- Graph edit

Tags: directshow, graphedit

Hey I have developed a directshow filter. But the issue is when i register the file on my system using regsvr32 and then open graphedit i cant see my filter there. 
One thing I need to tell here is that, I have to put my ax file in SysWoW64 in order to register that filter.
What is the problem.
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: What version of GraphEdit are you using? 32bit or 64bit? 32bit filters will only show up in the 32bit GrahpEdit, and vice versa

Comment: why do you need to put your filter in `SysWoW64`? What happens if you don't put it there? Can you search the registry for the guid you use?